# data upload showing different value in database codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a form from where am getting the value to be saved into database. Running the insertion query it's inserting into database but the problem is the phone number saved looks like this number " 2147483647" though in the query am passing the number 9846586583. Every time I insert its saving this number.

The data types of the column for phone number i have set is `int(16)`.

Below is the query that is displayed by `<?php $this->output->enable_profiler(true);?>` which shows a correct query

```
INSERT INTO `posts` (
    `country`,
    `city`,
    `area`,
    `street`,
    `house_no`,
    `house_type`,
    `floor`,
    `number_of_rooms`,
    `price`,
    `owners_phone`,
    `posted_by`,
    `featured_post`
)
VALUES
(
    'nepal',
    'pkr',
    'ratekhoire',
    'fulbari',
    '45',
    '1s',
    '0',
    '7',
    '10000',
    '9846586583',
    'bhabi',
    'Y'
)
```

Comment: change datatype to bigint(16)

Answer (score 0):

I would actually recommend changing from `int` to `String` (i.e. `varchar(numOfDigits)`) so you can allow prefix zeroes or pluses in the phone number. Then you can parse them with two helper methods.

`int(16)` has a maxvalue of 32767 since it's only 2 bytes = 16 bits (you can check that by converting the binary value `111111111111111` to decimal.

**ADDITION** The number `2147483647` has a binary equivalent of (`1100110011001100110011001100` which is just less than 4 bytes. (unsigned would be twice as big in decimal but not memory wise)

Answer (score 0):

**Reason:**

2147483647 is the largest **`int`** value for MySQL.
The reason is because the maximum value for signed integer is 2147483647. Even if you have specify INT(16) that doesn't mean that you can store up length of 16 because the maximum allowable value is 2147483647. The meaning of 16 in INT declaration is the length of padded zero and is only applicable if ZEROFILL is enabled on the column. But still the length cannot reach up to 16 characters.

If you have save the original data as 9846586583, it will be truncated into the maximum value of 2147483647.

**Solution:**

Just change the datatype from **`int`** to either **`bigint`** or **`varchar`**.